# FTP upload using filezilla on windows

Tags: svn, ftp

I have a folder wherein, the contents of this folder is a "checkedout" from svn, now whenever i do changes, I commit back to the repository..this time, I want to upload all the contents of this folder to the production server, but the problem is, there are .svn stuffs inside..so how will i upload the files via filezilla without having to upload including the .svn stuffs coz it eats space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the 'Directory Listing Filter' options (View > Filename filters). One of the options is SVN and CVS filters, which excludes those files from the listing.

A quick test on some of my files shows that if you drag a folder containing .svn folders to the remote host, the files are transferred, but not the .svn or its contents.

You can find out more about filters at: http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Filename_Filters

Comment: here's a screen shot.. http://s3.postimage.org/sv8332bw1/yii1.jpg   did i check the correct box ? or i need to check other boxes..please let me know which/what to do

Comment: That is the right box, and the only one that appears to be needed (you can view the details of what is being done by clicking 'Edit filter rules'). A suggestion: SVN adds the .svn folder to every folder - choose a small folder, perhaps with a couple of levels, and upload it to a test directory - verify that it works for you before starting the 'real thing'.

Comment: you mean I'll have to tick the checkbox at the right options(remote) ? based from the screenshot ? ...and not the one on the left side ?

Comment: No (I meant 'right' as in 'correct' - the screenshot need no changes) - if I understand your scenario correctly, you are uploading from your local machine to a remote server - you want to upload everything but the .svn folders - apply the filter to the local directories. The remote would apply if you were downloading from the remote server. My suggestion was to do a small test to ensure it worked as it should.